# Variable passed into function only changed within function

Tags: javascript

I created a simple function and I noticed something unexpected about javascript. When I pass a variable in to a function, then change it, its not changing outside that function. Heres some code:

```
function check(val, isEven) {
    if (val % 2 === 0){
    isEven++;
    console.log('incremented isEven is ', isEven);
  }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var isEven = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {

  check(arr[x], isEven);

  console.log('isEven is now ', isEven);
}
```

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hjs05k6r/).

Maybe I've been misinterpreting Javascript all these years, but I would have expected the `isEven` within `check()` to be the same as the original `isEven`.....But you can see in the logs, outside `isEven` stays as 0....

Comment: primitives are not passed by reference, you get a "fresh copy" that's scoped to the function. But note that your function does not do what you claim it does in your code: you've called it `check` but instead of returning some truth value, you're making it modify a value. Keep it `check`, and simply have it return whether an action needs to be taken or not.

Comment: JavaScript is purely pass-by-value, so a *copy* of the value of `isEven` is passed to the function.

Comment: This is how C family languages work.  If you want a variable altered by a function (1) the function has to assign to a variable like **y=f(x)** and (2) the function needs a **return** statement near the end to return a computed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects are passed by copying the reference to the object. Primitive types (string/number/etc) are passed by value.

This means if you passed in an object, modifying the object within the function would be reflected outside the function as inside and outside would both have references to the same object.

With a primitive type, the variable is copied when it is passed in and changes inside the function will no longer be reflected in the variable outside the function.